# A way to incentivise quality questions... Maybe?

Tags: discussion

I feel that the way to get quality questions is to incentivise a discourse about the technical and governance issues along with roll-out and deployment strategies.

To incentivise, allow payments to be made to the most upvoted comments.  Maybe on a monthly basis.  This could be a part of the research strategy for ongoing R&D which will allow a true democratisation and meritocracy of good knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Payments are not an option for this site.  The features are determined by Stack Exchange.

You would need to suggest it on the Stack Exchange Meta site.